# Wrapping Actions in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have an action:

```
class GetData
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        return ['some', 'data'];
    }
}
```

I have a cache action:

```
class CacheAction
{
    public function __invoke($callback)
    {
        return Cache::rememberForever(
            'key TODO',
            fn () => $callback
        );
    }
}
```

Then I wish to bind these in my service provider:

```
$this->app->bind(GetData::class, CacheAction::class);
```

But when I try an dependency inject `GetData` it errors saying it's not an instance of `CacheAction`.

How can I successfully wrap the `GetData` action with the `CacheAction`, so that whenever `GetData` is called, it is wrapped. I also hope to use the Cache wrapper around other actions too.